Efficiently standardize a large matrix in R with foreach/doParallel?
I need to standardize (subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation) the columns of several large matrices in R (roughly 300,000 rows by 10,000-20,000 columns).
The process has been very slow, so I tried to speed it up with foreach/doParallel, but that doesn't seem to be helping.
Some example code with a smaller matrix:
library('doParallel')
n.cores <- 7
clust <- makeCluster(n.cores,type='FORK')
registerDoParallel(cl = clust)

rows <- 300000
cols <- 1500
big_matrix <- matrix(runif(rows*cols),nrow=rows,ncol=cols,dimnames=list(paste0('r',1:rows),paste0('c',1:cols)))

# Attempt 1: No parallelization. Took 52.3 seconds.
system.time( stand1 <- scale(big_matrix,center=T,scale=T) )

# Attempt 2: Each column separately with foreach. Took 168.9 seconds.
system.time(
  stand2 <- foreach(mchunk=big_matrix,.combine='cbind') %dopar% { #
              (mchunk - mean(mchunk))/sd(mchunk)
            }
)

# Attempt 3: In chunks with foreach. Took 52.7 seconds.
stand_chunks <- function(mat,n.cores) {
  chunk_indices <- split(1:ncol(mat),cut(1:ncol(mat),n.cores)) # A list of column indices, splitting the matrix into n.cores chunks
  stand_mat <- foreach(ci=chunk_indices,.combine='cbind') %dopar% {
    scale(mat[,ci],center=T,scale=T)
  }
  return(stand_mat)
}
system.time( stand3 <- stand_chunks(big_matrix,n.cores) )

# Attempt 4: In chunks with foreach, without copying whole matrix to each worker. 23 seconds.
stand_chunks_v2 <- function(mat,n.cores) {
  chunk_indices <- split(1:ncol(mat),cut(1:ncol(mat),n.cores)) # A list of column indices, splitting the matrix into n.cores chunks
  mchunks <- lapply(chunk_indices,function(ci) { return(mat[,ci]) })
  stand_mat <- foreach(mc=mchunks,.combine='cbind') %dopar% {
    scale(mc,center=T,scale=T)
  }
  return(stand_mat)
}
system.time( stand4 <- stand_chunks_v2(big_matrix,n.cores) )


parallel::stopCluster(cl=clust)

# Attempt 5: Do matrix algebra and let BLAS handle it. 20.5 seconds.
RhpcBLASctl::blas_set_num_threads(7)
stand_matalg <- function(x) {
  means <- rep(1, nrow(x)) %*% t(colMeans(x))
  sds <- rep(1, nrow(x)) %*% t(apply(x,2,sd))
  return((x - means)/sds)
}
system.time( stand5 <- stand_matalg(big_matrix) )
summary(c(abs(stand1 - stand5))) # Still looks correct, plus or minus a bit of floating-point weirdness

I can understand why Attempt 2 was slow - the overhead of setting up workers just to have them each perform one quick little operation outweighs the benefits of parallelization.
Attempt 3 was very memory inefficient - it has the issue described here as "giving workers more data than they need" - if I watch the threads using the "top" command I can see the memory usage of each thread going up as the entire big matrix is copied for each worker. By the time I increase the matrix to 5000 columns, this copying is memory-wasteful enough that it will run out of memory on a HPC compute node with 80 Gb RAM. It also wasn't any faster than doing it without parallelization, possibly due to the overhead of copying the large matrix for each worker.
Attempt 4 was, finally, faster. It's definitely more memory-efficient than Attempt 2 - it duplicates the large matrix when it makes the mchunks list, but at least duplication is better than copying it to 7 workers. But it's probably still possible to improve on this further.
Attempt 5 (adapted from this answer to an old question) is the fastest so far, but it still requires the creation of two large "means" and "sds" matrices that match the dimensions of the original large matrix.
What's a more efficient way to standardize these large matrices (with foreach or via some other method)?

Additional information: I am working on an HPC cluster with plenty of RAM, so I probably don't need to use bigstatsr/file-backed matrices. I assume since disk I/O would always be slower than RAM, it's best to avoid that if I have enough RAM not to need it?

Unless you are doing everything by reference, you will run out of memory. Note that 'almost' everything in R is passed by value. For example, if you were to pass the matrix into the scale function, a copy would have to be created. Thats another memory chunk needed.  So consider using references. Also how are you loading the data into R? I would recommend using C/C++/Python. Note that 50K columns with 300K rows is ~120GB!! Not worth it to have that in memory. Consider doing two readings of the file. First to compute mean and sd, second to standardize and write back into the file

The matrix is being simulated in R, analysis will be performed on it, then only the results of the analysis (and not the matrix itself) need to be saved. So I'm hoping to keep everything in RAM during standardization and analysis, because if I can then the matrix never needs to be read/written to disk at all. It looks like 300,000x20,000 is 44 Gb, I don't expect to need one larger than that.

It is not good practice to include answers in the question.

@Friede OK, I took it back out! Sorry!

Try fscale() from {collapse}:
collapse::fscale(big_matrix)

I expect it to be comparatively rapidly fast. I am not too familiar with it's arguments, there might be potential for further speed ups.

Excellent! 2.9 seconds on the system I've been running the comparisons on!

Use package matrixStats.
system.time( stand1 <- scale(big_matrix,center=T,scale=T) )
# user  system elapsed 
#25.10    4.07   29.28 

library(matrixStats)
scaleM <- \(M) t((t(M) - colMeans2(M)) / colSds(M))
system.time( standx <- scaleM(big_matrix) )
#user  system elapsed 
#6.85    0.36    7.22 

all.equal(stand1, standx, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE

I don't think you can do much better without modifying the input matrix in place. That could be done, e.g., using RcppEigen.

If using matrixStats then use colMeans2. Also One could use Rfast package for speed. Could you compare the difference?

Very nice! 12.7 seconds on the system I've been running the comparisons on.

Another option could be RcppParallel.
